# How to find a domain name responsible for the email

Tags: email, exim

I have dedicated server with whm control panel. I have around 50 users in my servers. One of my client is sending email and i got abuse alert.I found the error from mail log. Can anyone look into it and help me from which domain that email is being sent

```
# less exim_mainlog | grep 1Qkx5n-98766v-4Y

2011-07-24 07:43:31 1Qkx5n-98766v-4Y <= stevena2@gmail.com H=xxx-xxx.xxx-xx.static-ip.oleane.fr (localhost) [xx.xxx.xxx.xxx] P=esmtpa A=dovecot_login:test@texxxxx.com S=3585
2011-07-24 07:43:34 1Qkx5n-98766v-4Y => matheve@yyyyy.com R=lookuphost T=remote_smtp H=mx2.mailbox.com [zz.zz.zz.zzz]

2011-07-24 07:43:34 1Qkx5n-98766v-4Y Completed
```

I want know to from which domain name email was sent to matheve@yyyyy.com

Answer (score 0):

Sure. It was sent from xxx-xxx.xxx-xx.static-ip.oleane.fr (localhost) [xx.xxx.xxx.xxx]

And if that is your server, then it was created locally from within the server. Probably a webmail software or a local script.